# How to define queries inside EF models using keyless entity types?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-core

I just stumbled over Entity Framework Core Feature called [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types). The listed [main usage scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#usage-scenarios) mention:

> Mapping to queries defined in the model.

I tried to find out what they mean using my favorite search engine, but couldn't find anything related. Can someone give me a hint or link the related documentation on how to define query-mapping inside EF Core models?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not an example of that in the doc, but it would look like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPostsCount>(
            eb=>
            {
                eb.HasNoKey();
                eb.ToSqlQuery("select Name, count(*) PostCount from BlogPosts group by Name");
                eb.Property(v => v.BlogName).HasColumnName("Name");
            });
```

Comment: How to do this via annotations?

Comment: Not everything can be set through annotations.  Although you are free to create custom annotations for your objects and then consume them in your fluent configuration.